# 2 d plot with intensity such as x, y, z without interpolation by python

Tags: python, each, point, contour

I have three groups of data, the lists of x, y, z values. To express these relations, I have usually used the contour functions such as  plt.contour or contourf or pcolor after interpolation with griddata module. However in this case I would show the intensity of value on specific grid without interpolation.
For examples, I will try to use two sets of x,y,z values (x,y,z and x1,y1,z1). 
If I use pcolor for both sets, it would be like:

```
myPLT = plt.pcolor(x,y,z,vmin=np.min(z),vmax=np.max(z))
myPLT1 = plt.pcolor(x1,y1,z1,vmin=np.min(z1),vmax=np.max(z1))
```

However, in this case, this two plots are overlaped and mixed. That is not what I would like to do. What I would like to do is to plot each point with intensity of z1 over myPLT distiguishably from the background plot of myPLT.

I have searched for this solution for long time, but I can't find. 
Any idea or help would be really appreciated.

Thank you,
Isaac

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for you to spend your precious time of my questions. I find what I would like to use. That is  "plt.scatter". By using it, I can solve my problem.
Thank you,
Isaac